# Why do we need to call HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme)?

Tags: cookies, oauth-2.0, identityserver4, .net-6.0, openid-connect

I am using Okta as an external IdP which is called via Identity Server 4.

I'm using this [example](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/signin_external_providers.html#handling-the-callback-and-signing-in-the-user) to trigger the challenge to Okta and have set up a Callback method.

In the example, under **Clean-up and sign-in:** it has:

```
// delete temporary cookie used during external authentication
await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme);
```

I had a look in F12 in Chrome and saw that the response from Identity Server's callback method had a `Set-Cookie` header which set the `Identity.External` cookie to empty.

**Is this necessary?**

**What is the benefit of doing this?**